# nHibernate adding new items for many-to-many relationship

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many

I have three entities in my music-related DB: *Video*, *Album* and *Genre*. Both videos and albums can have multiple genres, so I'm linking them with *many-to-many* association via a common table.
That's what I have in DB:

```
Videos: Id (int)
Albums: Id (int)
Genre:  Id (int)

Item_Genres: (table for many-to-many mapping)
   Id (int)
   objectType (here I have "album" for albums and "video" for videos)
   objectId (id from either Albums or Videos table)
   genreId (Id of the appropriate genre)
```

I have a problem with adding a new *Genre* to my *Video*.
When I do

```
videos.Genres.Add(genre);
```

nHibernate creates a row in Item_Genres table with the right *genreId* and *objectId* but with empty *objectType*. How can I fix that?

Here's my mapping for *Video* class:

```
<set name="Genres" table="item_genres" lazy="true" where="objectType = 'video'">
    <key>
        <column name="objectId" not-null="true"/>
    </key>
    <many-to-many class="Repositories.Entities.Genre">
        <column name="genreId" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-many>
</set>
```

With it I can request *Genres* for a *Video* from DB without any problem, the problem is only with adding new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that the only case is using a custom sql-insert.

```
<set name="Genres" table="item_genres" lazy="true" where="objectType = 'video'">
    <many-to-many class="Repositories.Entities.Genre">
        <column name="genreId" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-many>
    <sql-insert>INSERT INTO item_genres (objectId, genreId, type) VALUES ( ?, ?, 'video' )</sql-insert>
</set>
```

That worked for me.
Unfortunately, Fluent NHibernate doesn't support this :(

Comment: That is the only way to do it without using a mapped entity, as the `where` attribute only specifies how to filter the entities.

Answer (score 1):

A relationship like that really shouldn't be mapped as a many to many.  A true many to many should only contain objectId and genreId in your case.  You should map this relationship as a one to many on both sides and create an actual entity called ItemGenre that represents your item_genres table. Also note that this would change your class maps to use HasMany instead of ManyToMany. This would eliminate the need for your custom insert.

Comment: Why it shouldn't? I know, this is not a "classical" many-to-many, and I'll consider creating a separate table for each of Video/Album. But even in it's current state it's logically a "many-to-many", and it's much easier to handle it as many-to-many, without creating some entities in the middle